# Gem has wrong version for Jekyll

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I've installed latest Jekyll (3.3.1), but Gem/Ruby still thinks I'm on 3.2.1.  E.g.:

```
$ jekyll --version
/Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:203:in `rescue in start': Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll": (Bundler::VersionConflict)
  In Gemfile:
    jekyll (= 3.2.1)

    minima was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      jekyll (~> 3.3)
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:199:in `start'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:181:in `resolve'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:250:in `resolve'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `specs'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.3.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:36:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.3.1/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

The `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/` folder contains folders `jekyll-3.2.1` and `jekyll-3.3.1`.  Running `gem install jekyll` returns `Successfully installed jekyll-3.3.1`.  Any idea what the issue is here?

Comment: Your Gemfile says 3.2.1.

Comment: And it needs to say 3.3.1...

Comment: maybe you can try to `bundle update`.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Tried that. Ends with `Using jekyll 3.2.1`. It also reports `minima 2.0.0`, which looks inconsistent with Gem's message `minima was resolved to 2.1.0 `.

Comment: You probably have another gem that depends on jekyll 3.2.1 specifically. Try `bundle update jekyll` and there should be a warning.

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile change : `gem 'jekyll', '3.2.1'` for `gem 'jekyll'`.

Then : `bundle update`

Comment: I'm new to Gem so not sure which file this is. Google just returns documentation, which says `Place the Gemfile in the root of the directory containing the associated code`, which doesn't sound helpful.

Comment: Do you have a repository url ?

Comment: No I'm just trying to get this working for the first time, over a local IP